# Diagnosing by ruling things out

Tags: terminology, diagnosis

What is the technical term for a condition that is diagnosed by ruling everything else out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diagnosis of exclusion

> A diagnosis of exclusion (per exclusionem) is a diagnosis of a medical condition reached by a process of elimination, which may be necessary if presence cannot be established with complete confidence from history, examination or testing. Such elimination of other reasonable possibilities is a major component in performing a differential diagnosis.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnosis_of_exclusion